# Handling lots of id's in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web design and have a problem I don't really know how to solve in the most eloquent way. I have 7 weekday elements, each 2 dropdowns. A dropdown has 24 options, 1 for each hour of the day. That means 336 possible options a user can click on in total.

I need to assign a function to each of those 336 elements that will update the text in the corresponding box the dropdown menu came from.

I know how to do what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm not sure how to do it 'properly'. I could write my function that updates the text based on what you clicked on. Then I could go through and manually assign a unique ID to each of my 336 elements, then write a function that loops through and assigns my first function to all of them. Although this would mean manually assigning 336 unique ID's in my HTML. Something feels wrong about this? is there any better way?

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious that would make this much easier - maybe I'm taking a completely wrong approach?

[image: availability]

Comment: To better understand what you're trying to achieve, you should provide some sample code that illustrates your explanation.

Comment: Can you produce a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? If this is production code, you can just obfuscate it.

Comment: Event Delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use IDs and use just a single event for all elements.

There's a concept called event delegation, where you attach an event to a parent node, and it will handle that event for all child nodes. Since events "bubble up" in javascript, any event will eventually hit the parent node and trigger it. When that happens, you can check the original target of the event, and check if it's one of the classes you care about.

Here's an example: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Many libraries offer their own support for this, but it's actually pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a single `onclick` event handler to all 336 of your elements. Attached to the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) parameter that is passed to the event handler is a property `target`, which is the element on which the event was fired.

Then find the parent of this element (simply `node.parentElement`), and do your processing on it.

P.S. you don't need to have a unique id on an element in order to assign it an event handler.

Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.el').forEach(function(t) {
      t.onclick = func;
});
```

Comment: This will create 336 individual events, it's going to seriously impact performance on slower browsers. Check out Event Delegation (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead.

Comment: @CSturgess that's nice. however I think implementing it bubbling-down may be slightly trickier depending on how high you attach the event handler. OP may find it simpler to attach 336 event handlers to each of his elements. On that note, I doubt performance would be affected by event handlers. Do you have some references to the same?

Comment: Not really. The event object contains the details of the original element itself which can be used to do everything an individual event could do. And just because something is easier doesn't mean it's a good idea. Performance will DEFINITELY be affected by having hundreds of unnecessary event handlers. I learned about event delegation after doing something very similar to this that destroyed performance on mobile. Maybe you won't notice a real difference now, but learning to do it the right way now is still worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "`this`" keyword than assigning ids manually.

So instead of `document.getElementById(id)`you can use `this`

for example, instead of

HTML

```
<element id="myid" onClick="changer(myid);"> </element>
```

JS

```
function changer(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="changed";
}
```

**You may try**

HTML

```
<element onClick="changer(this);"> </element>
```

JS

```
function changer(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML="changed";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are other functions you can use to traverse the DOM. Check out the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) documentation.

There are countless ways to achieve what you want here, but I would do this by assigning a shared class like `day` to all your day options, and another class like `start-time` and `end-time` for the time options. Then I'd bind the function to all elements returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('day')`